# Propel is losing parameters to a query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, propel

```
->where("((Job.TwCountry = ? AND Job.TwAbroad = 1) OR (Job.TwCountry != ? AND Job.TwCountryTarget LIKE \"%?%\"))", array($site,$site,$site))
```

is part of a Propel 1.7 query. As you can see, the three parameters are the same. This does not work, here is the error:

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

As far as I can tell, the intermediary Propel representation uses the same array keys for all three parameters, thereby losing the fact that they should map to three different PDO parameters. Is there a way round this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's worth a guess - are you sure that `LIKE` takes a quoted string? I wonder if Propel does that for you?

Comment: Yes that was it. I actually figured it out about an hour ago, but add it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my guess:

```
->where(
    "((Job.TwCountry = ? AND Job.TwAbroad = 1) OR (Job.TwCountry != ? AND Job.TwCountryTarget LIKE %?%))",
    array($site,$site,$site)
)
```

The difference is that this Propel method is type-aware, and so will quote your `LIKE` parameter automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Move your wildcard characters from the query, and placed it on the parameter instead:

```
->where("((Job.TwCountry = ? AND Job.TwAbroad = 1) OR (Job.TwCountry != ? AND Job.TwCountryTarget LIKE ?))", array($site,$site,'%' . $site . '%'))
```